# web2py is not showing the images uploaded

Tags: image, web2py

I can't make web2py to show the images in one of my views.  I found similar threads in here, but most of them refer to thumbnails and 'blob'-stored images.

Here's what I have:

---

**MODEL**

```
db.define_table('foto',
                Field('archivo','upload'))
```

---

**CONTROLLER**

```
def mostrar():
    fotos = (db.foto)
    return locals()
```

---

**VIEW**

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{for foto in fotos:}}
    <img width="123px" src="{{=URL('download', args=fotos.archivo)}}" />
{{pass}}
```

---

As far as I understand, the above will allow me to see the images uploaded in the view, but instead I got broken-link images, like the following:

[image: screenshot of the issue]

If I try changing the `args` section within the `<img` tag, from `args=fotos.archivo` to `args=foto.archivo`, I get a `<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'Field' object has no attribute 'archivo'` error.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing some important concept here - I think that, if using `'upload'` as the type, you *save* the picture in the file system. However, I read somewhere that the `download` function is designed to work with that (file system stored file, not blob), and `upload` stores anything to the file system as long as it is used in a SQLFORM (same as I'm using in the above code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fotos = (db.foto)
```

Above, you are simply return the `Table` object. However, this object does not contain any records -- it is just a representation of the database schema. Instead, you must explicitly select records from the database:

```
fotos = db(db.foto).select()
```

The above is a shortcut for `db(db.foto.id > 0).select(db.foto.ALL)` (i.e., it selects all records and all fields).

Once you make that change, you should also change `args=fotos.archivo` back to `args=foto.archivo`.

Comment: You are great - pointed out the exact problem.  Thanks for your help with web2py; so far you have responded several of my questions, and you're always correct.